# Set maximum time for a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multithreading, async-await, timeout

I need to set a maximum time for a function in Javascript so the function will automatically stop after a certain time if it hasn't been finished yet,
Any solution how to do that?

```
function foo() {
   // foo() execute user script and it should stop after few seconds if the user did something wrong (like infinite loop) to avoid browser crash
}
```

Comment: Once you start synchronous code, you can't stop it from the same file. You can use [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers) and do `worker.terminate()` if it doesn't finish after a certain time.

Comment: Define "if it hasn't been finished yet". What does the function do? There's not enough information here for us to really help. Can you update your question with a [mcve]?

Comment: "*foo() execute user script and it should stop after few seconds if the user did something wrong (like infinite loop) to avoid browser crash*" yeah not possible. You're not just executing a function, you're just running arbitrary code. User code could be malicious in more ways than just having an infinite loop: `window.arr = []; setInterval(() => window.arr.push(1), 10)` will keep groing an array in memory without ever stopping. And would not block the thread. You need to sandbox that execution then nuke the sandbox when you're finished.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to execute your function on async mode, so you can controls it with promises:

```js
const foo = () => {
  let a = 1;
  while (a < 10000) a++;
  return 'Result ' + a;
}

const timeoutFunc = async (func, timeout = 0, errorResult = 'ERR')=>{
  let timeoutHandle;
  let mainHandle;

  const timeoutPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    timeoutHandle = setTimeout(
        () => { resolve(errorResult) },
        timeout
    );
  });

  const asyncPromise =  new  Promise((resolve) => {
    mainHandle = setTimeout(
       () => { resolve(func()) },
    );
  });

  return Promise.race([asyncPromise, timeoutPromise]).then(result => {
    clearTimeout(mainHandle);
    clearTimeout(timeoutHandle);
    return result;
  })
}
 
const tryToCallFunction = async (timeout)=>{
  const res = await timeoutFunc(foo, timeout); 
  console.log('FINAL RESULT: ', res)
}

tryToCallFunction(1); // this show timeout Error result
tryToCallFunction(11); // this show the correct result
```

Comment: No, you cannot cancel a running function through a promise. A promise is just a notification mechanism for async tasks. If you `Promise.race()` you can have a promise that resolves sooner but the task itself will still be running. That's not "cancelling" the execution at all.

Comment: I'm not cancel the promises but the settimeout execution

Comment: And that wouldn't stop `foo()` if it's already running.

Comment: if you try to execute the code in my example and add console.log into foo functions you can see that it executes once time (not in case of timeout error)

Comment: https://jsbin.com/wagelil/1/edit?js,console 1. It doesn't error 2. That is because `foo()` cannot be cancelled - it takes over the thread and no other async code can run until it finishes. 3. It *does* finish, it's not cancelled.